# Theory - calculating orders for next 12days from order history

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, forecasting

I'm using the following query to get the "forecast":

```
(select ROUND(sum(abs(l.piece))/count(distinct trunc(l.date_p)))*12
from vu_turnover l, orders_l cl where
regexp_replace(l.rid_v, '!.*', '') = cl.rid 
and cl.user = 46 -- not_stock_price
and TO_CHAR(l.date_p,'W') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'W') -- current_week
and l.date_p >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR'), -12) -- last_year
and l.code_id = item.id 
and Substr(cl.flags_s, 12, 1 ) = 2 -- executed_order
and l.code_o IS NOT NULL and l.partner in (X,Y))
```

It's working fine and returns the value of - `average of all piece which was sold through the current week(1-4) in the month at last + current year`. It's multiplied with 12.

Table `vu_turnover` looks like this (it's connected with `orders_l`):

```
orders_id    code_o    date_p    partner    piece    code_id    l.rid_v
00000123      01     01.01.2018    XY         5        2789    000014!03
00000124      01     01.01.2018    XY         5        2789    000014!03
00000125      01     12.02.2018    XY        10        2789    000015!08
00000128      01     24.03.2018    XY         5        2789    000034!05
00000129      01     05.05.2018    XY        10        2789    000119!09
```

In the table **are daily sales** by ID-s.

Is there any better IDEA to do a forecast for the next 12 days ?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Version: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle are two posibilities - you can use:

- linear regression,
- MODEL clause.

Unless you have stationary time series, average method is not very good.